# ¿Cómo puedo obtener la lista de mensajes enviados en Gmail?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, gmail

GmailApp es un servicio de Google Apps Script por medio del cual se puede acceder a la casilla de correo del usuario que ejecuta la secuencia de comandos (script). En la [página de referencia de GMailApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app) se incluye el método [getDraftMessages()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#getDraftMessages()) pero no existe uno similar para los mensajes enviados. ¿Cómo puedo obtener los mensajes de la carpeta enviados?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gmail, en lugar de utilizar carpetas para organizar los mensajes utiliza etiquetas, de las cuales hay de dos tipos principales, etiquetas del sistema y etiquetas del usuario.

> Nota: De acuerdo a [Managing Labels](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/labels) las etiquetas Borradores (`DRAFTS`) y Enviados (`SENT`) son etiquetas del sistema que no pueden ser asignadas por el usuario.

Además de [getDraftMessages()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#getDraftMessages()), existen otros métodos par obtener mensajes con etiquetas del sistema, pero como se menciona en la pregunta no hay uno así para los mensajes con la etiqueta enviados. En cuando a la [Clase GmailMessage](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/#gmailmessage), existe el método [isDraft()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message#isDraft()) pero no hay uno similar para preguntar si un mensaje tiene la etiqueta del sistema `SENT`.

Por lo anterior, la alternativa que queda es usar una búsqueda, con base en [Operadores de búsqueda que puedes usar con Gmail](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=es), con el operador `in:sent` ó `label:sent`.

El siguiente ejemplo registra en el log el número de hilos con la etiqueta `SENT`.

```
function cantidadEnviados () {
   // Encuentra los mensajes ENVIADOS
   var threads = GmailApp.search('in:sent');
   var cantidad = threads.length;
   Logger.log('La cantidad de hilos en Enviados es ' + cantidad);
}
```

> Nota: Para obtener una lista de mensajes en lugar de una lista de hilos, deberá usarse el servicio avanzado de Gmail, más específicamente [users.messages.list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list)